# ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using SciPy to minimize the variance:

```
port_returns=[]
port_variance=[]
for p in range(4000):
    weights = np.random.random(5)
    weights /=np.sum(weights)
    port_returns.append(np.sum(returns.mean()*245*weights))
    port_variance.append(np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(returns.cov()*245, weights))))

def min_variance(weights):
    return np.array(port_variance)

cons = {'type':'eq', 'fun':lambda x: np.sum(x)-1}    
bnds = tuple((0,1) for x in range(245))
optv = sco.minimize(min_variance, 245*[1.0/245,], method='SLSQP', 
                    bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
```

I tried to run this function but got the error below:

```
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 458, in minimize
  constraints, callback=callback, **options)    
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 370, in _minimize_slsqp
  raise ValueError("Objective function must return a scalar")    
ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar
```

How can I return a scalar value?

Comment: *How can I return a scalar value?* Just do it :) Seriously, show us the implementation of the objective function `min_variance` and the data that goes in, then somebody may be able to tell you how to fix the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.  As a minimum, this question does not tell us what `noa` or `min_variance` is.

Comment: "np.array([port_returns,port_variance,port_returns/port_variance])": you'll want to minimize *one* of these, not all three.

Comment: Even with the added code it's hard to tell what is your minimization variable.  It sort of looks like `weights` but `port_variance` is calculated before hand.  And as for the immediate error, `min_variance` returns an array, not a single 'cost' value.  I suspect you need to step back and run some demo cases, to get a clearer idea of what this function is doing.

Answer (score 1):

upgrade scipy to v1.0. It was a bug in 0.19